# WPF: Layout dynamic content so that there's only a scrollbar if necessary, otherwise content expands to fill space

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to layout a set of TextBoxes, vertically, one on top of the other. If there are so many TextBoxes that they cannot fit within the Window height then I want a ScrollBar to become available on the Window. The number of `input` TextBoxes is variable. There is always a last TextBox with the name `output`.

If all the TextBoxes can appear within the Window height then I want the last TextBox to stretch to the bottom and fill all the remaining space. In addition, if the `output` TextBox has a lot of Text then I want this TextBox to make a ScrollBar available.

Here's some pseudo XAML of what I have:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="input1" Margin="12, 12, 12, 12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox Name="input2" Margin="12, 60, 12, 12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox Name="input3" Margin="12, 108, 12, 12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        ...
        <TextBox Name="inputN" Margin="12, ((N - 1) * 48 + 12), 12, 12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox Name="ouput" Margin="12, (N * 48 + 12), 12, 12" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem I have right now is that if the `output` TextBox has a lot of content then it increases in height and has the Window present a ScrollBar. Instead I want the `output` TextBox to get the ScrollBar.

I can fix that problem by removing the ScrollViewer that is holding the Grid. However if I do that I get another problem. Because the number of `input` TextBoxes is variable, if there are so many that not all the TextBoxes can show in the Window, the Window doesn't get a ScrollBar, which I need.

I have tried playing around with putting a MaxHeight on the `output` TextBox, but if there are few `input` TextBoxes and a tall Window then I'm apt to not fill all of the remaining vertical space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to wrap your Output TextBox in a ScrollViewer and also assure it does stay in the bottom (defining some rows in the Grid or docking it to the bottom of a DockPanel.

EDIT: Do you need something like this?

```
<Grid x:Name="grd01">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

SECOND EDIT:

```
<Grid x:Name="grd01">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox x:Name="input"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>

  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBox x:Name="output"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This comes close, but doesn't work when there are lots of `input` TextBoxes. In that case I need a scrollbar to become available on the Window. I tried to make your example work by putting the whole grid inside a ScrollViewer, but then I get the original problem again.

Comment: If you wrap the grid in a ScrollViewer the problem comes back. Put the ScrollViewer in the Row 0 (inside the grid), and put inside the panel of your choice with the other inputs. The ScrollViewer should be restricted by the row and you'll finally have two scrollable sections.

Comment: This is really good and may be the best that can be done without complex logic in the code behind file (which I'd like to avoid). The picky issues with it are that it fixes the height of `output` and I'd like to have it stretched if there is room in the window. Also it creates two scrollbars (one for each row). If possible I'd prefer one scroll that spans both rows. I know that's picky so I'll accept your answer if I can't figure out a better solution in the next day or so.

Comment: The fixed height can be resolved by something like
`<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="200" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>`. So that just leaves the fact that the scrollbar is only for the first row. I'm not seeing any easy way to get around that, but I don't think it's a problem to go with it. I'll make an edit to answer to show my change and accept it.

Comment: Good to know it somehow works for you. Have you tried a DockPanel?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tweak on the window loaded event with this code:
**EDIT**:
i modified it so it's even correct if resizing now

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        output.MaxHeight = output.ActualHeight;
        output.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        output.Height = output.MaxHeight;
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        output.MaxHeight = output.MinHeight = output.Height = outGrid.ActualHeight;
    }
```

-

```
<ScrollViewer Height="Auto">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="outGrid">
            <TextBox Name="output" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: This also comes close. However, when there's a lot of text in `output` I'm getting a scrollbar on both the Window and `output`.